# Readonly multidimensional array property, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, getter-setter, magic-methods

I've been fooling with `ArrayAccess` and PHP's magic (*`__get`, `__set`*) for awhile now, and I'm stuck.

I'm trying to implement a class in which some properties, which are arrays, are read only. They will be set initially by the constructor, but should not be modifiable thereafter.

Using `__get` magic by reference, I can access array elements arbitrarily deep in the properties, and I was thinking I can throw exceptions when those properties are targeted via `__set`.

The problem is though, when I'm accessing the value of an array element, PHP is calling `__get` to return that part of the array by reference, and I have no knowledge of whether or not its a read or write action.

<sub>(*The worst part is I knew this going in, but have been fooling with `ArrayAccess` as a possible workaround solution, given the properties were instances of an implemented object*)</sub>

Simple example:

```
class Test{
    public function &__get($key){
        echo "[READ:{$key}]\n";
    }
    public function __set($key, $value){
        echo "[WRITE:{$key}={$value}]\n";
    }
}

$test = new Test;

$test->foo;
$test->foo = 'bar';

$test->foo['bar'];
$test->foo['bar'] = 'zip';
```

And the output:

```
[READ:foo]
[WRITE:foo=bar]
[READ:foo]
[READ:foo] // here's the problem
```

Realistically, I only need the value `foo` (*as per my example*) anyways, but I need to know it's a write action, not read.

I've already half accepted that this cannot be achieved, but I'm still hopeful. Does anyone have any idea how what I'm looking to accomplish can be done?

I was considering some possible workarounds with `ArrayAccess`, but so far as I can tell, I'll end up back at this spot, given I'm going to use the property notation that invokes `__get`.

---

**Update:** Another fun day with `ArrayAccess`.

<sub>(*This is a different issue, but I suppose it works in. Posting just for kicks.*)</sub>

```
class Mf_Params implements ArrayAccess{

    private $_key       = null;
    private $_parent    = null;
    private $_data      = array();
    private $_temp      = array();

    public function __construct(Array $data = array(), $key = null, self $parent = null){
        $this->_parent  = $parent;
        $this->_key     = $key;
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            $this->_data[$key] = is_array($value)
                ? new self($value, $key, $this)
                : $value;
        }
    }

    public function toArray(){
        $array = array();
        foreach($this->_data as $key => $value){
            $array[$key] = $value instanceof self
                ? $value->toArray()
                : $value;
        }
        return $array;
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset){
        if(isset($this->_data[$offset])){
            return $this->_data[$offset];
        }
        // if offset not exist return temp instance
        return $this->_temp[$offset] = new self(array(), $offset, $this);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value){
        $child = $this;
        // copy temp instances to data after array reference chain
        while(!is_null($parent = $child->_parent) && $parent->_temp[$child->_key] === $child){
            $parent->_data[$child->_key] = $parent->_temp[$child->_key];
            $child  = $parent;
        }
        // drop temp
        foreach($child->_temp as &$temp){
            unset($temp);
        }
        if(is_null($offset)){
            $this->_data[] = is_array($value)
                ? new self($value, null, $this)
                : $value;
        }else{
            $this->_data[$offset] = is_array($value)
                ? new self($value, $offset, $this)
                : $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset){
        return isset($this->_data[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset){
        unset($this->_data[$offset]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a second class, implementing `ArrayAccess`, to use instead of your arrays. Then you will be able to control what is added to the array with the `offsetSet()` method:

```
class ReadOnlyArray implements ArrayAccess {
    private $container = array();
    public function __construct(array $array) {
        $this->container = $array;
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        throw new Exception('Read-only');
    }
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if (! array_key_exists($offset, $this->container)) {
            throw new Exception('Undefined offset');
        }
        return $this->container[$offset];
    }
}
```

You can then initialize your `ReadOnlyArray` with your original array:

```
$readOnlyArray = new ReadOnlyArray(array('foo', 'bar'));
```

Comment: Thanks **Benjamin Morel**; As I mentioned to **cweiske**, I figured; I'm starting to think the PHP object engine needs to be reviewed; instances like this, as well as lack of support for `&offsetGet()` are quite frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for the update too; I appreciate the code suggestion. As I mentioned in my comment to **cweiske** also, I've been struggling with `ArrayAccess` also, but for a different reason. I'm abandoning my attempt at the `ArrayAccess` fiasco, but check my question update to see it.

Comment: Not very clear what's wrong with your implementation if you don't tell us what you expect from it and what's not working :)

Comment: True. (*I was editing it, and it's more-or-less unrelated, just thought I would share*) It nearly works as expected; no notices are thrown when non-existent array indices are accessed, or the containing arrays (*of a given nested element*) are written to. Issue is, `isset` always returns true, and incrementing a non-existent array index casts the temporary object to `int` (*throwing an error*) I'm hoping PHP will soon add support for `__toInt`, `__toArray`, etc. Not much I can do about that now.

Comment: @Benjamin Morel: That blob of code I posted; while I did so just for kicks, I'm wondering - is what I'm trying to achieve there possible too? In your provided answer, you throw and exception when the offset doesn't exist. I'm working in an environment with the highest error reporting (*`-1`*) and of course notices get tossed around whenever I point at non-existent array indices. I'm trying to overcome this, as the intent of this data structure is a loose one, without the otherwise strict limitations imposed by the error reporting. Any ideas?

Comment: @TomCat, if your intent is not to report an error when a non-existing offset is accessed, then just `return null;` instead of throwing an exception!

Answer (score 2):

You could not return by ref, which would solve the problem of changability, but would not allow changing of some values that are allowed to be changed.

Alternatively you need to wrap every returned array in ArrayAccess, too - and forbid write access there.

Comment: Thanks *cweiske*; I sort of figured that. I've been struggling with `ArrayAccess` also. I've become a fan of the highest error reporting level (*`error_reporting(-1);`*) and have been fighting tooth and nail with PHP to stop throwing notices for a single class type when non-existent array indices are accessed/written to. I'm thinking I may just leave responsibility to the client programmer not to modify the values.